# Localhost (xampp ) not found

Tags: xampp, windows-10, localhost

After the latest windows 10 update cycle Apache stopped working. I changed the port ID from 80 and 443 but no success. I reinstalled Xampp but  no luck and again changd de id of the ports.
Now I'm working with port 8012 for apache and 8013 for apachessl. All necessary files and the Xampp control panel are adapted.
 So now I can start all connections on the control panel of Xampp
BUT 
 Apache does not serve any pages : I tried localhost/index, localhost:8012 , /127.0.01 , and so on; the result is always that the page is not found.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Change it back to port 80 for the moment. Can you access any pages? For example, if you type just "localhost" into your browser (no quotation marks), do you see anything?

Comment: Hi Oloff, thanks for the reply
Port 80 is used by the system and that's why the Apache do not start.
But in the meantime, I have removed  all the new extensions that have been installed during the latest windows update
Now I when i go to loclahost:8012  I'm coming to the dashboard of the Apache Frinds. In order to enter a specific project I must specify the name of the project localhost:8012/myproject, but I can no longer see a list of all my projects on the loclhost.